# Uncaught TypeError: L.geoJson.ajax is not a function Leaflet.js Heatmap.js

Tags: leaflet, heatmap

Hello I'm facing this error that l.geoJson.ajax is not a function. I can't understand why I am facing this error. I read somewhere that we have to place `leaflet.ajax.min.js` file in the root directory but it still does not works. can somebody explain to me what is it that I am doing wrong. Here is the code to the js:

```
map = L.map('hmap',{center: [53.15, -6.7],zoom: 10});

    // OSM Baselayer
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

    var kildareStyle = {
        "fillColor": "#CC9933", 
        "color": "#000000",
        "weight": 2,  
        "fillOpacity": 0.2
    };

    var pointStyle = {
        radius: 8,
        fillColor: "#ff7800",
        color: "#000",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.8

    };
     var kildare = new L.geoJson.ajax('assets/kildare.geojson', {style:kildareStyle}).addTo(map);
// var points = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('assets/kildare.geojson').addTo(map);

var heat = L.heatLayer(heat_points, {radius:12,blur:25,maxZoom:11}).addTo(map);
```

Can somebody explain to me what is it that I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're [loading the Leaflet.AJAX javascript file in your HTML](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax/blob/gh-pages/example/index.html#L18), right?

Comment: I'm loading that like this `<scritp src="./leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I don't know how but I replaced the code in `leaflet.ajax.min.js` again and it started working. but now I'm facing another error that `L.heatLayer is not a function`.

Comment: `Leaflet.Heat` is also a plugin that needs to be loaded before you can use it: `<script src="leaflet-heat.js"></script>` Full documentation and download is here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat

Comment: @iH8 that was my first my thought that I may have not included the `leaflet-heat.js` file but I have included that file to

Comment: Are you sure you're loading it after the `leaflet.js` file? The `leaflet-heat.js` depends on the Leaflet library, so it should be loaded _after_ the actual leaflet library. The order of loading assets is important.

Comment: @iH8 Yes I am loading it after leaflet.js 

 here is a screen shot of my file path. [file paths](http://screencast.com/t/8NpGE6RE)

Comment: If you're getting no other meaning full error messages it's best that you setup a proper [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and post it with the relevant code and information in a new question because comments aren't meant/fit for asking new questions and answering them. Please accept the current answer if it answered your question and post a new one. You'll get more attention/help that way and keeps things nice and tidy.